# Why do I have a coax splice behind this blank face plate?

Tags: wiring, coaxial-cable

Behind this blank face plate is a coaxial cable. I already have a coaxial cable in the middle of this room that I use for cable.

[image]

I'd like to just push this into the wall and patch up the hole but I'm not sure if its used for anything.

Answer (score 8):

It is likely a remnant from either the initial cable-pulling process, or that connected cable is an extension that was used to "move" the coax to that other point in the room that you mentioned.  I would see what happens if you disconnect it - does the coax stop working somewhere else in your house?  That's the surest way to find out what it is used for.

Since it is a connection, having the access box is handy if you ever need to tighten the connection / move the coax port back to this box.  I don't think there is any code requirement on having access in this instance, though, as it's a signal wire (low voltage) - not power. (as always, IANAL)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Guess ill leave it as is.

Comment: Another reason: I had a splitter at a coax outlet i wasn't using. I replaced the splitter with a coupler and put a blank faceplate at the box so the downstream outlets would have a 3dB bump in signal power. Edit: Actually my carpets and walls looked a lot like yours too

Answer (score 6):

I get we all want smooth walls, but **you really shouldn’t just cover up a splice box**.

While that is a less serious problem with data cable, it is absolutely essential it not be done with power cables, especially AC mains!

The reason is that splices do fail (whereas cables in walls generally do not).   You need to be able to access each end of the cable for testing and repair.

Further, you are looking at the matter from the perspective of the room as it’s arranged currently.  It’s quite likely this is the original location of the coax outlet, and you’re seeing an extension cable to the present location, because someone agreed with your arrangement.  It’s even possible you arranged the room that way because that’s where the coax or other utilities were located. You or someone else might want to arrange the room differently.  You could swap cover plates with the present outlet, and make this the live outlet instead.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying this is a code requirement even for low-voltage / data cables?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs -- while the Code doesn't require it for LV cables, boxing in a LV/comms splice is generally just going to bite you in the butt later

Answer (score 2):

It's a just a coupling - a splice.  There are many reasons it may have been installed, but the most likely is to relocate the TV that was originally in that location.  You can close it up inside the box without any issue.

Comment: If by "close it up" you mean put the cover plate back on it, then by all means yes. If you mean, "put drywall over it to permanently hide it", then I'd suggest that's a _very_ bad idea. While it's low voltage and may not legally be required to be accessible, cable connectors do go bad and when the TV signal fades and the cable guy can't figure out why...